# Selecting Next HTML Sibling in Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and I am creating a "push a keyboard button to progress this black square across" kind of game. I am trying to figure out how to create a native javascript function that allows:

a keypress to give a `<td>` element the class of "active" that is next in line (or sibling) to a `<td>` that already has the class "active". I also want to have the 'current' `<td class="active">` element to remove it's "active" class at the same time.

So far I have managed to create a function that allows a click on a `<td>` and adds the class "active" on the `<td>` selected while at the same time removing any "active" class from its surrounding siblings. Instead of clicking I want to give "active" to the next `<td>` when pressing the letter 'm'.

Apologies if I am bad at explaining: here is my code:

```js
var racerTable = document.getElementsByClassName("racer-table");
var p1items = document.getElementById("player1-strip").querySelectorAll("td");

var lastp1 = p1items[p1items.length-1];

for (var i = 0; i < p1items.length; i++) {
  p1items[i].addEventListener("click", player1Race);
}

function player1Race() {
  for (var i = 0; i < p1items.length; i++) {
    p1items[i].className = "";
  }
  
  // The expression below is where I need help
 
  this.className = "active";
  
  if (lastp1.className === "active") {
   alert("Player One Won!");
  } else {
  
  }
}
```

```css
.racer-table td {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.racer-table td.active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table class="racer-table">

    <tr id="player1-strip">
      <td class="active"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sean_johnson/bgdb716d/139/

Comment: replace `this` in the click event with `document.querySelectorAll("td.active");` also look into `elm.nextElementSibling`, it can save you some typing...

Comment: Cells in a table have a [*cellIndex*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-tdth-cellindex). If the next cell to be visited is in the same row, just get the one with the next highest index. E.g. `row = cell.parentNode; nextCell = row.cells[cell.cellIndex + 1]`. Rather than putting a listener on every cell, consider putting  a single listener on the table (search for event delegation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML** - note the addition of the tabindex attribute which allows the element to be focused and thus the keydown event to fire.

```
<body>
  <table class="racer-table">
    <tr id="player1-strip" tabindex="1">
      <td class="active"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Get the player's strip
var control = document.getElementById("player1-strip");

// Add an event handler to the strip (tr)
control.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

  // Get the current active td
  var active = document.querySelector(".active");

  // Get the letter from the key pressed, lowercase it 
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
  var next;

  // Show it in the console (Firebug)
  console.log(letter);

  // Act on the key
  switch (letter) {
    case 'm':
      // Get the next cell in the row
      next = document.querySelector(".active + td");

      // Remove the active class from the current active cell
      active.classList.remove("active");

      // If there is another cell
      if (next !== null) {

        // Make the next cell active
        next.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        console.log('Done');
      }
      console.log(next);
      break;
  }
});
```

This is a simple example.  You can extend the *switch* statement to handle more keys.

Written under Firefox on CentOS - you may need to adjust the code for other browsers or OSs.

Comment: You're a legend, works a charm - I was on this for 2hrs + , Cheers for this.